# change() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X' while predicting future value

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, lstm

I am trying to predict the future value with three inputs. Here I want to forecast the future value according to the three inputs in every one hour. Here g= temperature, p=humidity, c=wind and I want to predict temperature in next hour according to these inputs. That's why here I put n_out is 1, I wrote the code in def class. After that I tried to add that def class value as x,y value. Because I am going to write it as train and test value. But the error came as this. I am going to predict future value using LSTM . After this I don't know how to add this code as train and test into LSTM model. Can anyone help me to solve this problem? 
Here I paste my code and csv file.

```
def change(train,X, n_out=1):
    data = train.reshape((train.shape[0]))
    x, y = list(), list()
    in_start = 0
    # step over the entire history one time step at a time
    for _ in range(len(data)):
        # define the end of the input sequence
        in_end = in_start + X
        out_end = in_end + n_out
        # ensure we have enough data for this instance
        if out_end < len(data):
            x_input = data[in_start:in_end, 0]
            x_input = x_input.reshape((len(x_input), 3))
            x.append(x_input)
            y.append(data[in_end:out_end, 0])
        # move along one time step
        in_start += 1
    return array(x), array(y)


data= pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['g','p','c']) 
data.columns = ['g', 'p', 'c',]
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.0f}'.format
data = data.dropna ()
cols=['g', 'p', 'c']
X=data[cols]
x,y = change(data)
```

The error came as

[image]

my csv file:

[image]

Aftre edditing the code it gave me this error:

[image]

Comment: Please post text as text, not pictures. And make your code match the error messages. Anyway what do you not understand about `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'reshape'` exactly?

Comment: Furthermore, what are you trying to achieve with `train.reshape((train.shape[0]))`? It does not make any sense to me.

Comment: @Goyo LSTM() layer must specify the shape of the input. ... array of data when fitting the model and when making predictions, ... We can then use the reshape() function . That's why I tried to reshape the data value.

Comment: I do not see how that answers any of the questions I asked you. Did you understand my questions? BTW the first one is probably more important.

Comment: @Goyo for the first question  Does panda.dataframe is builtup reshape? if it is should I have to change my code with values?

Comment: @Goyo For the second question I'm just trying to flatten the data

Comment: `pandas.DataFrame` does not have a method `reshape`. Numpy arrays do. So `train.reshape` will raise an exception if `train` is a `DataFrame`.

Comment: @Goyo So can you help me to change my code? I tried so many methods to run my code.

Comment: I do not even understand what the purpose of your code is. I suggest you focus in solving one issue at a time. So maybe start by not calling `.reshape` on a `DataFrame`. Then if there are still issues, choose one and try to solve it, etc.

Comment: @Goyo Thank you for the response. I solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

In your definition of the function you have 3 parameters:
train, X and n_out=1

```
def change(train, X, n_out=1)
```

when you are calling your function you are providing just 1 argument(`data`)

```
x,y = change(data)
```

how `n_out` you define as 1, you need to provide `x` also, or define your function as:

```
def change(train, n_out=1)
```

**NOTE:**

you need to provide X when you are calling your function for example :

```
x,y = change(data, 1)
```

or define functrion like :

```
def change(train, X=1, n_out=1)
```

Comment: i want to predict one value according to these three inputs. Okay if I remove this x,y=change(data) , then how I can add this into the train model to predict value using LSTM. Do you have any idea for this? If I removed then how I can write the input data in code.

Comment: you need to provide X when you are calling your function for example : x,y = change(data, 1) , or definet it for example like : def change(train, X=1, n_out=1)

Comment: Yes I tried   this method then it gave me long error. After tried your method the error is showing (reshape)

Comment: can you provide what is your data here: pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['g','p','c'])

Comment: g= temeprature ,p=humidity ,c = wind According to these inputs I want to predict temperature in next hour

Comment: I thought about the variable "data"

Comment: No it's not, Sorry for my bad question. Actually I tried to solve this, but still I can't find the good answer for this.